# Ctrl-C to stop the shell script execution

Tags: shell, signals, copy-paste

I have a shellscript as follows. This doesn't terminates on pressing Ctrl-C. Can you guide me on how to modify the following code to kill the execution on Ctrl-C as input.

```
#!/bin/bash

validateURL()
{
        regex='(https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Za-z0-9\+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9\+&@#/%=~_|]'
        string=$1
        if [[ $string =~ $regex ]]
        then
                echo "0"
        else
                echo "1"
        fi
}

RED='\033[0;31m'

echo -n "Enter the URL :"
while read URL_REGISTRY
do
        if [ $(validateURL $URL_REGISTRY) == "0" ]
        then
                break
        else
                echo -e "${RED}Wrong URL entered."
                tput sgr0
                echo -n "Enter the URL again :"
        fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks I know that. But I want to use ctrl-C only. :)

Comment: I don't see why it won't terminate on Ctrl+C. Is this the correct scipt? Do you `trap` cal anywhere in your code that ignores SIGINT?

Comment: Just thats my entire script. When I press Ctrl-C, it just prints "^C" and thinks it is wrong input and continues with reading input again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way this can happen is if your shell blocks `SIGINT`. As per your description, your shell seems to do it. Reset the `SIGINT` in your shell so that your script receives `SIGINT`.

Run the following in your shell and run the script:

```
trap - SIGINT
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding this to my script solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
stty intr "^C"
```

If that does not work, try:

```
stty -a
```

and figure out what is wrong with your settings. If you can't, update your answer with the output of stty -a.

Also make sure that you have not trapped the interrupt signal (2) as mentioned in the other answers.